# sorting string lengths using comparator

Tags: java

While trying to sort an array based on its element string lengths, I am struck with a compile error. I have an set to start with, ,

```java
Set<String> arraycat = new HashSet<String>();
//add contents to arraycat
String[] array = arraycat.toArray(new String[0]);
//array looks like this now:
//array=[cat,cataaaa,cataa,cata,cataaa]
```

I would ideally want to sorted to

```java
array=[cat,cata,cataa,cataaa,cataaaa]
```

so I have a comparator of type

```
class comp implements Comparator {

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and then I call the class by

```java
Collections.sort(array, new comp());
```

but then, it throws me two compile errors:

```
comp is not abstract and does not override abstract method   compare(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object) in java.util.Comparator
class comp implements Comparator {
^
testa.java:59: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.lang.String[],comp)
location: class java.util.Collections
Collections.sort(array, new comp());
^2 errors
```

I would appreciate any clues to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved same by using stream and comparator as below-

```
Arrays.stream(array)
      .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
      .forEach(a -> System.out.print(a + " "));
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to specify a type parameter for `Comparator` for your implementation to work.

```
class comp implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
      return 1;
    } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

In Java 1.7 and later, you can also simplify the body of this method to:

```
class comp implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
  }
}
```

Also, `Collections.sort` sorts `List` objects. Since you're sorting an array, you should use [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-):

```
Arrays.sort(array, new comp());
```

Comment: Hi Lawrence.. thanks for this.. That has solved the first compile error: but, Ive still got another compile error saying: "cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.lang.String[],comp)
location: class java.util.Collections
  Collections.sort(array, new comp());" I have imported the util* package, not sure why I am getting this error

Comment: [`sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) takes a `List`, not a `String[]` array. Use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) to convert it.

Comment: Also, for a simpler comparator, consider using [`Integer.signum(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum(int)) instead of the `if/else-if/else`; e.g. `return Integer.signum(o1.length() - o2.length());`

Comment: Thanks Rob: you were correct: the data were of incomptatable types. I have sorted it now. Thanks again.

Comment: this question is too old but anyway... there is no need to convert the array to list, you can sort it like that: `Arrays.sort(array, new comp());`

Comment: @RobHruska If JDK >= 1.7, one can even use `Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length())`.

Comment: Thanks RobHruska, Master_ex and ChthonicProject. I've updated the answer based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `Arrays.sort()` method if data source is an `array`.

For instance,

```
String []array={"first","second","third","six"};

Arrays.sort(array,new Comparator<String>()
{
  public int compare(String s1,String s2)
   {
    return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
});
```

Or convert array to List to use Collections.sort() method,

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(array),new Comparator<String>()
{
  public int compare(String s1,String s2)
   {
    return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**One Liners**

Ascending

```
Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

Descending

```
Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed());
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
class comp implements Comparator<String> { ...
```

or even better

```
Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<String> { ...
```

(and not even name the class that's only used once)

Comment: You need to specify the type-variable! Comparator *<String>*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar assignment recently and I'll provide you with an additional example.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
//for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

/**
 *
 * @author Xilef
 */
public class StringKorter implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        if (s1.length() > s2.length())
         return 1;
        else if (s1.length() < s2.length())
         return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] woorden = { "boot", "kinderen", "stoel", "volwassenen", "ei", "stoel", "kop", "zeshoek", "stoel", "ei" };
        System.out.println("woorden: " + Arrays.toString(woorden));//before sorting by length
        Arrays.sort(woorden, new StringKorter());
        System.out.println("Array woorden after sorting by length: " + Arrays.toString(woorden));
    }
}
```