# string manipulation in java array

Tags: java, arrays, string

this code is designed to initialise an array C and its values, then print them and print the largest  string within the array. i have used an enhanced for loop. the debug showed an error that 'longest name' was not initialised so i added =null to it when declaring the string but the output of the program always prints null now rather than the longest string in the array please help!

```
package week14;

public class LabArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int [] A = new int[5];
        int [] B = new int[5];
        String [] C = {"luke", "elliot", "glenn", "jonny", "jack"};
        int [] D = new int[5];
        int length = C[1].length();
        String longestname;
        int nextlength;
        for (String name: C){
        System.out.println(name);
            nextlength = name.length();
            System.out.println(name.length());
            if (nextlength > length){
                length = nextlength;
                 longestname = name;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nthe longest word in the array = " + longestname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632857/sorting-string-lengths-using-comparator

Just use the sort method of Collections or Array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for initial value in the length  you assign the second element of the array which is already the String with the biggest size(elliot) ,so you never getting inside the if loop and you never assign a value   to longestname,

Initialize the value of the longestname as well

```
int length = C[1].length();
String longestname=C[1];
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to just start the length at zero, but this also works.

Comment: should i not initialise the above two variables at the [0] array address?

Comment: You can use any of the array's element for initial value,but the standard way is to use the first element

Comment: @DonRoby ,what if the array had only empty Strings? you gotta think all the possibilities

Comment: Indeed you're right.  You definitely should also start the value at the empty string if you're going to start the length at zero.

Answer (score 0):

THis code works perfectly :

```
    int [] A = new int[5];
    int [] B = new int[5];
    int [] D = new int[5];        
    String [] C = {"luke", "elliot", "glenn", "jonny", "jack"};       
    String longestname=null;
    int maxlength=0;
    for(String max:C)
    {
        if(maxlength<max.length())
        {
            maxlength=max.length();
            longestname=max;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nthe longest word in the array = " + longestname);
```

**output :**

```
run:

the longest word in the array = elliot
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```