# How to sort String array by length using Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to sort an array of strings according to their length using `Arrays.sort()`, but this sorts the strings lexicographically rather than by length. Here is my code:

```
S = "No one could disentangle correctly"
String W[] = S.split(" ");
Arrays.sort(W);
```

After sorting :

```
correctly
could
disentangle
no
one
```

but what I want is

```
no  //length = 2
one //length = 3
could //length = 4 and likewise
correctly
disentangle
```

How can I get the above output? Please give answer for JDK 1.7 & JDK1.8.

Comment: Create your own comparator.

Comment: @matt So u mean I can not achieve this through Arrays.sort()

Comment: No I mean to use the 2 argument version of Arrays.sort(Object[], Comparator).

Comment: Arrays.sort() sorted the strings alphabetically. What is the sort criteria you wanted it to use instead? That's the part you will need to write your own comparator for.

Comment: Your expected  Output is not sorted actually

Comment: What is the pattern in your expected output?  What metric are you using to describe that as "sorted", and why did you think that would be the default output or `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: Are you sorting by length? This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632857/sorting-string-lengths-using-comparator

Comment: @Jane,@Vikrant yes actually length is my criteria.

Comment: @ZohraKhan you are not specific and down-voted my answers .. you are just a wow .. Nothing more to say.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using *JDK* 1.8 or above then you could use *lambda expression* like **matt** answer. But if you are using *JDK* 1.7 or earlier version try to write a **custom Comparator** like this:

```
String S = "No one could disentangle correctly";
String W[] = S.split(" ");
Arrays.sort(W, new java.util.Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        // TODO: Argument validation (nullity, length)
        return s1.length() - s2.length();// comparision
    }
});
```

Answer (score 47):

For java 8 and above

```
 Arrays.sort(W, (a, b)->Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));
```

A more concise way is to use Comparator.comparingInt from [Mano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866382/2067492) here.

Answer (score 36):

Alternative to and slightly simpler than matt's version

```
Arrays.sort(W, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

Comment: This could also open up using more complete comparators. `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());`

Comment: How to get it in descending order?

Comment: `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed()`

Answer (score 5):

Simply changing the parameter position we can sort in descending order.

```
Arrays.sort(W, (a,b)->b.length() - a.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 is pretty easy. as mentioned in the above answer.
I was solving some problems on hackerrank and there they are using java 7. so I had to write the java7.
That is selection sort. though time complexity is not great O(n^2) however it serves the purpose.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // I am taking list and again converting to array. please ignore. you can directly take array of          string and apply the logic.
        List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfString.add("because");
        listOfString.add("can");
        listOfString.add("do");
        listOfString.add("must");
        listOfString.add("we");
        listOfString.add("what");
        String[] w= new String[listOfString.size()];

        for(int i =0;i <listOfString.size();i++) {
            w[i] = listOfString.get(i);
        }
        // That is for java 8
        //Arrays.sort(w, (a, b)->Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));

        for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
                for(int j=i+1;j<w.length;j++) {
                    String tempi = w[i];
                    String tempj = w[j];

                    if(tempj.length()<tempi.length()) {
                        w[i] =w[j];
                        w[j]=tempi;
                    }
                }
        }

       // That is for printing the sorted array
        for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(w[i]);
        }
```

**Output.**

```
do
we
can
must
what
because
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is kind of irrelevant to this question (***I wanted to sort and a list not an array***) but since the answers provided here helped me solve my error, am going to leave it here for those that are facing the issue had.

```
Collections.sort(vehicles, (VehiclePayload vp1, VehiclePayload vp2) 
    -> Integer.compare(vp2.getPlateNumber().length(), vp1.getPlateNumber().length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer Streams in Java8 onwards then you could use -

```
String input = "This is a beautiful world";
String[] arr = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
                     .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                     .toArray(String[]::new);
// prints output
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

The output is -

```
[a, is, This, world, beautiful]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class SortStringArray
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String S = "No one could disentangle correctly";
        String W[] = S.split(" ");
        Arrays.sort(W, new StringLengthComparator());
        for(String str: W)
        System.out.println(str); //print Your Expected Result.
    }
}
 class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<String>{ //Custom Comparator class according to your need

    @Override
        public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
            return str1.length() - str2.length();// compare length of Strings
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

//possible but not recommended;

```
 String sp[]="No one could disentangle correctly".split(" ");
    
    for(int i=0;i<sp.length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<sp.length;j++)
        {
            if(sp[i].length()>sp[j].length())
            {
                String temp=sp[i];
                sp[i]=sp[j];
                sp[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(String i:sp) //will print content of array sp
        System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("diamond");
    list.add("silver");
    list.add("gold");
    
    System.out.println(list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

output:

```
[gold, silver, diamond]
```