# Get the median length from an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, median

I've very new to Java and I wanted to get a calculation but it keeps coming back wrong. I'm trying to get the median length of words added to an arraylist. I find codes to do this with arrays but I can't seem to find a solution to doing this with an arraylist.

This is my code:
(individual string words are added through a text field)

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

double wordLength;
double average;
double middle;
String medianNum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...

    middle = 0;

    for (String word2 : stringList) {
        wordLength = stringList.length();
        middle = wordLength / 2;
    }

    if (middle % 2 == 1){
        medianNum = String.format("%.2f", middle);
    } else {
        medianNum =  String.format("%.2f", ((middle-1) + middle)/2.0);
    }

    // Add/Update the average number to the textview
    medianLength.setText(medianNum);


}
```

Comment: To get median length you need to sort array from shortest to longest or vice versa and get the middle length if array size is odd, and if it is even you have to calculate average of middle elements.

Comment: I've read this before, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I know I sort by using "Collections.sort(stringList);", that's as far as I know.

Comment: @Tuby how can you calculate average of two elements when his collection contains strings?

Comment: @v3gut http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866240/how-to-sort-string-array-by-length-using-arrays-sort

Comment: @Os. they will be sorted by length so he can calculate average using String.length()

Comment: All the codes to get the median I have found are all using integers, but I'm using strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, sort the array depending on the strings length. Can be achieved by passing the Comarator to the sort function as follow:

```
Collections.sort(stringList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        return  s1.length() - s2.length();
    }
});
```

Then, get the middle as follows:

```
if (stringList.size() % 2 == 1) {
    middle = stringList.get(stringList.size()/2).length();
} else {
    middle = (stringList.get(stringList.size()/2).length()
           + stringList.get(stringList.size()/2-1).length()) / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I didn't know about Comparator.